# User specific Jira notification in Slack

Tags: jira, bitbucket.org, slack

I'd like to integrate our Jira with slack, but it seems the standard plugin just dumps everything into a channel, which with a team of 200+ isn't really an option. What I'd love is to be able to replace the barrage of email notification (i.e. when you are mentioned, assigned to or watching a ticket) with messages into a specific channel/private message for each user.

Does such a thing exist, or do you know of a way to achieve this kind of functionality with a custom app?

(It would also be great to get the same thing for BitBucket with pull request notifications)